# Issue w/ TezosJ_SDK wallet

Tags: wallets

I was just trying to create a wallet using TezosJ_SDK specifically using Pocket and I have enchanted the following error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not initialize Android KeyStore.`

The code I have is:

```
import milfont.com.tezosj_android.model.TezosWallet;

...

TezosWallet pocketWallet = new TezosWallet("password123", "DEV123", TezosNetwork.ALPHANET, 60000); 

Log.d("new wallet is", pocketWallet.getPublicKeyHash());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently it is not a TezosJ_SDK related issue, but a problem with using a KeyStore inside JUnit Tests on Android Studio.

To solve this issue and continue developing with TezosJ_SDK on Android Studio, just move your code from the test unit to MainActivity onCreate() method. It will work.